# Buscar frequência em tabelas MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Eis a minha dúvida.
O sistema (PHP) possui 6 tabelas (MySQL) idênticas que são as participações de usuários em determinados eventos. Cada entrada na tabela é unica mas os dados podem se repetir nas tabelas.
O que eu não estou conseguindo fazer é buscar nessas 6 tabelas quais usuários participaram de todos os eventos.

```
+-------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id                | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| idPiloto          | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| pontosGanhos      | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| pontosDeduzidos   | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| carteiraGanhos    | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| carteiraDeduzidos | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| dnf               | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| dq                | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| dqRe^             | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| bateriaGrid       | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| posicao           | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| posicaoRe^        | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: Se as tabelas são identicas, por que você não normaliza elas? Faça com que todos os dados fiquem na mesma tabela e diferencie através de uma coluna nova.

Comment: E não tem como respondermos sem ver a estrutura das tabelas.

Comment: Post a estrutura da tabela, mas pelo que você falou parece que usar `JOIN` entre as tabelas resolve.

Comment: Não entendi a idéia de tirar a tabela. Ajudaria nas respostas.

Answer (score 2):

Sem ver as tabelas é meio difícil de te dar uma solução, mas a `query` ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
SELECT u.*
  FROM usuarios u
 WHERE EXISTS(SELECT x.*
                FROM (SELECT * FROM tabela1 AS t1
                      UNION
                      SELECT * FROM tabela2 AS t2
                      ...
                      UNION
                      SELECT * FROM tabela6 AS t6) x
               WHERE x.usuario_id = u.usuario_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma solução.

```
SELECT COUNT(*), TABELA, idPiloto FROM (
    SELECT 'TAB1' AS TABELA, idPiloto FROM TABELA1
    UNION 
    SELECT 'TAB2' AS TABELA, idPiloto FROM TABELA2
    UNION   
    .....
    SELECT 'TAB6' AS TABELA, idPiloto FROM TABELA6  ) A
GROUP BY TABELA, idPiloto
HAVING COUNT(*) = 6
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta. Tirando o **TABELA** do **GROUP BY** funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: Aqui funcionou como esta. Porém eu testei no SQL-Server e não no MYSQL.